# Google Maps. Отслеживание клика по метке

Tags: google-maps-api, карты, google-analytics

Доброго дня всем!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Google.Analytics создать цель для отслеживания клика по метке на карте, какие события и куда надо прописать?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет следующая документация Гугл: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=ru ++ https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=ru ++ https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=ru

Comment: Спасибо, изучу более подробно